# String search in List<T> with high performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a list of 50000+ string with an average lenth of ~1000 chars. I can do a simple query like this:

```
data.Where(c => c.Contains(query));
```

But my guess is that this is not the best way when it comes to performance. What is your sugestions when trying to boost the performance in the search?

Things that i have tried:

```
/*** Worst ***/
var result = new List<string>();
foreach (var row in data)
{
    if (row.Contains(query))
        result.Add()
}

/*** Medium ***/
data.Where(c => c.IndexOf(query) != -1);

/*** Best but not that great ***/
data.Where(c => c.Contains(query));
```

Comment: _"my guess is that..."_ - don't guess, measure. You will have to loop over all strings at least once and you will have to start walking all strings for the `query`. What have you tried?

Comment: 500000 x 1000 = 500 million characters = 1000 million bytes =1 million kilo bytes = 1000 MB = 1 gigabyte. Are you sure you are manipulating this amount of data or did I make a calculation error?

Comment: Start using a database ;)

Comment: Sorry there were one 0 to many should only be 50000 and unfortinetly i don't have access to any database in the current situation and this have to be handled in memory becaus data only exists in memory. Permanent storage is on SD-card so performance is bad.

Comment: @Tim a text-based search/index engine (lucene, etc) would usually be more appropriate here

Comment: Maybe Boyer–Moore string searching? How long is the query usually?

Comment: Yeah, I'd use Lucene or a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) in this case.

Comment: Query is normaly 10-25 chars long.

Comment: @Andreas Boyer–Moore is probably worth trying then, but not super great. Would work better with longer queries.

Comment: What about using StringCollections? They probably have some performance improvements ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head: you can use `PLINQ` to improve the search response time (if your machine is multi-core)

```
var result = data.AsParallel()
    .Where(c => c.Contains(query));
```

Other than that, as **@Tim Schmelter** pointed out, you should use a database table.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to use a database - use it. They are very good at querying quickly.

If you can't and you need to do it in memory, you can use any fast string searching algorithm that finds a short string in a long string. Depending on exactly what you need, here are two suggestions:

- Knuth-Morris-Pratt ([C# implementation](http://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2012/08/18/the-knuth-morris-pratt-string-search-algorithm-in-c/)) - useful when you are looking for the same string repeatedly in many "databases of strings"
- Suffix tree ([C# implementation](https://suffixtree.codeplex.com/)) - useful when searching many times for different strings in the same "database of strings"

Any of those algorithms is useful for finding a short string P in a long string S. They efficiency varies according to what changes and what remains static.

In your case, you have a list of strings instead of a long string. But the problem of searching in a list of strings is easily convertible to the problem of searching in a long string by concatenating all strings an separating by a special character that is not used by any of them.

For example, if I want to look for a string P in the list of strings ["Hello", "World", "Forty two"] then I will create a long string "Hello$World$Forty two" (where $ is my special separator) and look for P in this long string.